# (Sharepoint JSON) Is it possible to change icons for a sharepoint list column based on checkboxes?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a list where I am trying to keep track of new parts for our company, and I want to set a progress bar to track how each item is progressing as it is introduced to the company. However, my boss wants to use checkboxes to mark certain stages as complete, so I was wondering if there is a way to set the JSON format script to select the correct progress bar icon depending on which or how many checkboxes are filled in. there are four checkboxes with the following names: CompareDrawingstoBOM, NewPartisScheduled, MaterialSecuredinNPL, ProgrammingComplete. I'm not really familiar with JSON at all so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic JSON introduction that you could reference:

[Site template JSON schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema)

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Try using below JSON code on your choice field:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
}
```

How `join()` works:

`join()` takes 2 operands. The first is an array (multi-select person or choice field) and the second is the separating string.

Returns a string concatenation of the array values separated by the separating string.

Example for multi-select choice field:

`"txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ', ')"` --> This will result in Apple, Orange, Cherry (depending on the selected values)

Example for multi-select person field:

`"txtContent": "=join(@currentField.title, '|')"` --> This will result in Chris Kent|Vesa Juvonen|Jeff Teper (depending on the selected persons names).